# create new folder while saving the file (not before...)

Tags: pantheon-files, files

The option to create new folder while saving a file seem to have disappeared in Odin?

Am I missing something? or is it another "improvement" in Odin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of Flatpak packaging and sandboxing, I think.  You do not say which apps you find are affected but I suspect they are Flatpak'd or using the FileChooser portal rather than directly.  It may depend on what filesystem permissions they request and are granted.

Comment: Thank you! The app that caused me to post this question was Firefox (and yes installed using Flatpak, not sandboxed). I didn't have this problem in Hera but there Firefox was not using Flatpak... There may be other apps affected. Will have to try re-installing Firefox without Flatpak and see if it makes difference

Answer (score 0):

I have un-installed Flatpak version of Firefox and installed download directly from Firefox.

One problem solved, but:

1. how do you "integrate" my downloaded directly version with
   elementary OS ???

   later edit:

   I have used `sudo apt install firefox` instead of downloading directly from Firefox and all is well!
2. how does one bring the issue with Flatpak to the attention of EOS developers? I would prefer to use Flatpak but not at the expense of lost functionality...

Comment: I have also removed Flatpak version of Thunderbird, which had problems with loosing Local Folders directory...

Comment: There is one advantage to not using Flatpak version - Firefox is quicker to launch !!!

Comment: I have two other Flatpak apps (Okular and GIMP) both work fine with respect to this issue, so it seems it is only Mozilla (Firefox and Thunderbird) that are affected...

Comment: Elementary developers are aware of the problem (and several others caused by Flatpak). I am sure that if there is a solution that is not contradictory to the security goals of Flatpak then it will be fixed at some point, either in elementary or upstream.