# Thunderbird local folder

Tags: thunderbird

Elementary OS 6 Odin
Thunderbird 91.2.1 (64-bit) flatpak - 1.0

All is working fine apart from Local folders occasionally not connecting (they are located on NAS, which connects at boot perfectly fine)
It is a simple matter of editing the settings every time it happens (Thunderbird re-starts and all is fine)but...

it was all (and still is) working fine in EOS 5 , so why is it not working in EOS 6 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is caused by Flatpak.

un-installing Flatpak version and replacing it with:

```
sudo apt install Thunderbird
```

solves the problem.

It appears to be common problem for Mozilla apps, see also:

[another Odin/Mozilla Flatpak issue](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29027/create-new-folder-while-saving-the-file-not-before)